# How can I delay an HTTP response for x seconds?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, http

I won't go into the boring details of why I need this, it's part of an internal analytics package, but my goal is to create an ASP.NET page that returns a redirect after 2 seconds.

The problem I'm seeing is that using `Thread.Sleep(2000);` is going to hold up one of my ASP.NET ThreadPool threads. As I understand it, this is pretty wasteful as thread creation isn't cheap and I need this server to handle as many possible simultaneous connections as possible.

So, what's the best way to have HTTP GETs to my page return after **at least** 2 seconds (over 2 seconds is no problem, it just can't be under).

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Response.Redirect(RedirectUri);
    }
```

**EDIT**

I should clarify, the requested page is actually requested as an image, so returning HTML isn't possible. It'll be used like so:

```
    <img src="http://hostname/record.aspx"/>
```

The redirect to an actual image should take 2 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement `IHttpAsyncHandler`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

You can do this on the markup itself, you can put something like:

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=otherpage.aspx">
</head>
```

Comment: Apologies for missing out a key part of this, see my edit. Sorry!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control of that, it might be used anywhere, even email clients that wouldn't support meta redirects or JS. All I can rely on is an IMG tag.

Comment: @MatthewBrindley and can't you have a "bridge" page; something whose only purpose is to wait for 2 secs and then actually redirect to the real URL? I know it sounds hacky but better than implementing an IHttpAsyncHandler as other users have suggested :P

Comment: @Icarus - meta tags will be ignored if the browser is expecting an image.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in JS:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $.ajax({url: './script.aspx'});
},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way simple way to delay program execution without holding up a thread. You could in theory set up a a delay at the other server where the Re-Direct is occurring, but if you are just trying to cause a delay or timeout prior to the Redirect, you'll have to pay the penalty of a waiting thread.